# Prove $\lim_{a \to -\infty} \left(-\ln |a| -\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a^n}{n(n!)}\right)$ equals the Euler-Mascheroni constant

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find a series representation for $\text{li} (t)$. Through a substitution and  the comment of @user1952009  and @soke I'm managed correct my answer to get :

$$\text{li} (t)=\lim_{\epsilon_0 \to 0^+} (\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon_0} \frac{e^x}{x}dx +\int_{\epsilon_0}^{\ln t} \frac{e^x}{x} dx)$$

[about integral logarithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828638/about-integral-logarithm/1828651#1828651)

Even with the correction, everything reduces nicely with the Taylor series except that I need to find:

> $$-\lim_{a \to -\infty} \left(\ln |a| +\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a^n}{n(n!)}\right)$$
>
> I know this is equivalently:
>
> $$=-\lim_{a \to \infty} \left(\ln a +\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a^n(-1)^n}{n(n!)}\right)$$
>
> $$=\lim_{a \to \infty} \left(\ln (\frac{1}{a}) +\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a^n(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n!)}\right)$$
>
> But how can I reduce this to:
>
> $$\lim_{a \to \infty} (h_a-\ln a)=\gamma$$

I can confirm that it does indeed converge to $\gamma$ as wolfram alpha gives me:

> $$\ln (\frac{1}{a}) +\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a^n(-1)^{n+1}}{n(n!)}=\Gamma (0,a)+\gamma$$

But how could I manipulate my expression to get to there?

(Question 2) is solved @user1952009

I also have another question. I found:

$$\text{li}(t)=\gamma+\ln t+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{t^n}{n(n!)}$$

Is this somehow resembles what is found in Wikipedia  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function (scroll to series representation). Yet is wrong.

I think there is some confusion in my limits of integration:

Start with

$$\text{li} (e^x)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{0}^{1-\epsilon} \frac{dt}{\ln t} +\int_{1+\epsilon}^{e^x} \frac{dt}{\ln t}$$

Now the substitution $t=e^x$ so $dt=e^xdx$:

$$\text{li} (t)=\lim_{\epsilon_0 \to 0^+} (\int_{-\infty}^{-\epsilon_0} \frac{e^x}{x}dx +\int_{\epsilon_0}^{t} \frac{e^x}{x} dx)$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean to have a $-\varepsilon_0$ in the first integral in the first line?

Comment: No, the $a$ came about when I tried to evaluate the integral at $-\infty$ did I do something wrong ?

Comment: I don't know much about the topic in question, but I was wondering because it seems you're (rightfully) trying to avoid integration at $x=0$, however the interval $(-\infty, \varepsilon_0)$ certainly contains zero when $\varepsilon_0 > 0$. Oh, also, I meant "a (a as in the word, not the variable) negative epsilon naught", not "a minus epsilon naught", I think you confused that

Comment: Yes you are correct @soke. Do you think you can help me with my second question?

Comment: How will that help me? I already directly applied the Taylor series to $e^x/x$. @user1952009

Comment: The expression you developed did something strange with the substitution. The first limit does not equal $li(t)$ it instead it equals $li(e^t)$

Comment: Do you know what led me to get such wrong result @PaulLeVan  please scroll down to the bottom of my question

Comment: @PaulLeVan : yes he messed up between $Li(t)$ and $Li(e^t) = Ei(t) =\int_{-\infty}^t \frac{e^x}{x} dx$ for $t < 0$. for $a < b < 0$ :   $Ei(b)-Ei(a) = \int_a^b \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!} dx = \ln|b| - \ln|a| + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b^n - a^n }{n \, n!}$ and he wants to prove $\displaystyle\lim_{a \to \ -\infty} - \ln|a| - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n }{n \, n!} = \gamma$ so that $Ei(b) = \gamma + \ln |b| + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{b^n }{n \, n!} $

Comment: Could you please help me see where I went wrong in my steps without using $Ei(t)$ and $Li(x)$ @user1952009

Comment: For some reason my comment got deleted but @user1952009  thanks so much. If you can help me with the limit , perhaps a hint, it would be great also.

Comment: $li(e^x) = \int_{0}^{e^x} 1/(\ln(t)) dt =\int_{-\infty}^x e^u / u du$ The variable naming got a little messed up.

Comment: I got that part @PaulLeVan thanks anyway.

Comment: starting from $\gamma = \int_0^\infty (\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}- \frac{1}{x}) e^{-x} dx$ is useful, since $\int_a^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}} dx = -\ln(1-e^{-a})$ and $\int_a^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx = Ei(a)$. can you finish from here ? ($\ln a -\ln(1-e^{-a}) = -\ln(\frac{1-e^{-a}}{a})$ which converges as $a \to 0^+$)

Comment: Yes I'm going to try that.

Comment: I'm stuck with $\gamma=\lim_{a \to 0+}[\ln (1-e^a)+\int_{a}^{\infty} \frac{e^u}{u}du]$ I tried the Taylor series on $e^u$ but it gives me a wierd result with $a \to 0+$ and another variable $w \to \infty$.

Comment: why the Taylor series ? no it gives you that $Ei(a) = \ln a + \gamma$ as $a \to 0$

Comment: Yes I got it thanks.@user1952009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Consider for](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) $t > 0$ : $$F(t) = \int_{t}^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx = -Ei(-t)= -Li(e^{-t})$$

for $0 < a < b < \infty$ : $$F(a)-F(b) = \int_a^b \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx = \int_a^b \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!} dx = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_a^b \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!} dx$$ $$ = \ln b - \ln a + \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{b^n - a^n }{n \, n!}$$

[then use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals) $$\gamma = \int_0^\infty (\frac{1}{1-e^{-x}}- \frac{1}{x}) e^{-x} dx  = \lim_{a \to 0^+} -\ln(1-e^{-a}) - F(a)$$

so that $$\gamma = \lim_{a \to 0^+}  - \ln(1-e^{-a})+\ln a - \ln a- F(a) = \lim_{a \to 0^+} -\ln(\frac{1-e^{-a}}{a})-F(a) - \ln a $$ $$= \lim_{a \to 0^+} -\ln a-F(a) $$

hence 
$$-\gamma- F(b) = \lim_{a \to 0^+} F(a)+ \ln a  - F(b) =\lim_{a \to 0^+}  \ln b -  \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{b^n - a^n }{n \, n!} = \ln b -  \sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{b^n }{n \, n!}$$

Answer (score 2):

First, we may switch to positive numbers in order to preserve my brain, then prove that:
$$ \lim_{a\to +\infty}\left(-\log a+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} a^n}{n\cdot n!}\right) = \gamma. \tag{1} $$
Now we may notice that:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} a^n}{n\cdot n!}=\int_{0}^{a}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1} x^{n-1}}{n!} = \int_{0}^{a}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx \tag{2}$$
and that, by Frullani's theorem,
$$-\log(a)=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-ax}-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-x/a}}{x}\,dx \tag{3}$$
so our limit becomes:
$$ \lim_{a\to +\infty}\left(\int_{0}^{a}\frac{1-e^{-x/a}}{x}\,dx+\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-x/a}}{x}\,dx\right)\tag{4}$$
where:
$$ \int_{0}^{a}\frac{1-e^{-x/a}}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-e^{-x}}{x}\,dx \tag{5}$$
and 
$$ \lim_{a\to +\infty}\int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}-e^{-x/a}}{x}\,dx = -\int_{1}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx \tag{6}$$
We may use integration by parts and get that our limit is given by:

> $$ -\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x}\log(x)\,dx = \color{red}{-\Gamma'(1)}=\color{blue}{\gamma}\tag{7}$$

through [the Weierstrass product for the $\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Alternative_definitions).

Comment: I edited my answer, can you see if it works now. I know the integral diverges but the limit does too. So they in a sense may cancel each-other out?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: it does not work: $$1 =\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left[(n+1)-(n)\right]\stackrel{?}{=}\lim_{n\to +\infty}(n+1)-\lim_{n\to +\infty} n = \infty-\infty = \lim_{n\to +\infty}(n+2)-\lim_{n\to +\infty} n \stackrel{?}{=} \lim_{n\ to +\infty}(n+2-n) = 2.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> **The Question**:
>   $\ds{\lim_{a \to -\infty}\bracks{-\ln\pars{\verts{a}} -
>      \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {a^{n} \over n\pars{n!}}} =             \gamma\,.\quad\gamma}$: *Euler-Mascheroni Constant*.

---

\begin{align}
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {a^{n} \over n\pars{n!}} & =
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {a^{n} \over n!}\int_{0}^{1}x^{n - 1}\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {\pars{ax}^{n} \over n!}\,{\dd x \over x} =
-\int_{0}^{1}{1 - \expo{ax} \over x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] & =
-\int_{0}^{-a}{1 - \expo{-x} \over x}\,\dd x =
-\ln\pars{\verts{-a}}\pars{1 - \expo{a}} + \int_{0}^{-a}\ln\pars{x}\expo{-x}
\,\dd x
\end{align}

---

Then,
\begin{align}
&\color{#f00}{\lim_{a \to -\infty}\bracks{-\ln\pars{\verts{a}} -
     \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} {a^{n} \over n\pars{n!}}}} =
-\int_{0}^{\infty}\ln\pars{x}\expo{-x} =
-\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\mu}\expo{-x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm] = &\
-\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{\Gamma\pars{\mu + 1}}{\mu} = -\Gamma\,'\pars{1} = 
-\Gamma\pars{1}\Psi\pars{1} = -\Psi\pars{1} = \color{#f00}{\gamma}
\end{align}