# Conditional convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

Prove that the series
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n}$$
is conditionally convergent?

I tried to prove that it is not absolutely convergent series by trying to prove that $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\vert\cos(n)\vert}{n}$ is divergent, but I did not succeed. Is there another way?

Comment: Hint:  [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Comment: I used Dirichlet's test to prove the convegence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n}$ now I need to prove divergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\vert\cos(n)\vert}{n}$.

Comment: if you make a plot of $\max(|\cos(x)|,|\cos(x+1)|)$, you will notice it is always $\ge 0.4$. This means for any $m$, at least one of $|\cos(2m)|$ and $|\cos(2m+1)|$ is $\ge 0.4$. So the sums $\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{|\cos n|}{n}$ diverges as least logarithmically.

Answer (score 4):

[Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) does the job pretty nicely. Let we prove that the partial sums of $\cos n$ are bounded:
$$ \left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\cos(n)\right| = \left|\frac{\sin\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{2\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}\right|\leq\frac{1+\sin\frac{1}{2}}{2\sin\frac{1}{2}}<\frac{14}{9} $$
and we are done, since $\left\{\frac{1}{n}\right\}_{n\geq 1}$ is a sequence monotonically decreasing to zero.

We may even compute the value of the series: by summation by parts,

> $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos n}{n}=\text{Re}\left(-\log(1-e^i)\right)=\color{red}{-\log\left(2\sin\frac{1}{2}\right)}=0.0420195\ldots $$

On the other hand, the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\left|\cos n\right|}{n}$ is clearly divergent by a simple combinatorial lemma: given three consecutive integers $n,n+1,n+2$, for at least one of them the value of $\left|\cos(\cdot)\right|$ is greater than $\sin(1)$, hence:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{3N}\frac{\left|\cos n\right|}{n}\geq \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{\sin(1)}{3k} $$
and the RHS is divergent as $N\to +\infty$.

Comment: Did you see my comment. I really need your help. If you don't feel like checking it out I totally understand.

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: your question actually asks for proving the conditional convergence, and my answer does. If you want a proof that the series is absolutely divergent, please suitably modify your question.

Comment: Huh it's not this specific question. I'm asking if you may please check my answer to another question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828884/prove-lim-a-to-infty-left-ln-a-sum-n-geq-1-fracannn-ri. Thanks. If you scroll down you will see it. Again, you don't have to but I feel strongly if you say it's correct then it's correct.

Comment: @Jasmine: same old story: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297452/sines-and-cosines-of-angles-in-arithmetic-progression

Comment: Jack, please, could you write in a detailed way how it is possible to get the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\dfrac{\cos n}n\;?\;$ I am also interested in the proof of combinatorial lemma.

Comment: Jack, please read my answer and tell me if my proof of combinatorial lemma is ok or if it can be improved in some way. How would you prove it?

Answer (score 1):

We can use Dirichlet's test to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos n}n$ is convergent. Note that
$$
    \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\cos n|}n > \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos ^2n}n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{2n} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2n}{2n},
$$
where $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1{2n}$ is obviously divergent and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos 2n}{2n}$ is convergent by Dirichlet's test. Hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\cos n|}n$ is divergent, implying $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos n}n$ is conditionally convergent.

Answer (score -1):

Too long for a comment.

Jack in his answer used the following combinatorial lemma, so I asked him to write the proof.
Since he has not written it yet, I have tried to write one by myself.
If someone knows how to get a better and shorter proof, please give me a hint about it.

**Combinatorial lemma:** Given three consecutive integers $\,n\,,\,$ $\,n+1\,,\,$ $\,n+2\,,\,$ for at least one of them the value of $\,\left|\cos(\cdot)\right|\,$ is greater than $\,\sin1\,.$

**Proof:** Since $\,n\,$ is an integer which is a rational number, there does not exist any $\,k\in\Bbb Z\,$ such that $\,n\in\left\{1-\frac\pi2+k\pi,\,\frac\pi2-1+k\pi,\,\frac\pi2+k\pi\right\}.$
Moreover, for any $\,n\in\Bbb Z\,$ there exists $\,k\in\Bbb Z\,$ such that
$1-\frac\pi2+k\pi<n<\frac\pi2-1+k\pi\;$ or $\;\frac\pi2-1+k\pi<n<\frac\pi2+k\pi\;$ or $\;\frac\pi2+k\pi<n<1-\frac\pi2+(k+1)\pi\,.$

If $\;1-\frac\pi2+k\pi<n<\frac\pi2-1+k\pi\,,\;$ then $\,-\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)<n-k\pi<\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)\,,\;$ so $\,\cos(n-k\pi)>\cos\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)=\sin1\,,\;$ hence $\,|\cos n|=|\cos(n-k\pi)|>\sin1\,.$

If $\;\frac\pi2-1+k\pi<n<\frac\pi2+k\pi\,,\;$ then $\,(k+1)\pi-\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)<n+2<(k+1)\pi+\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)\,,\;$ so $\,-\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)<(k+1)\pi-(n+2)<\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)\,,\;$ therefore $\,\cos[(k+1)\pi-(n+2)]>\cos\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)=\sin1\,,\;$ hence $\,|\cos(n+2)|=|\cos[(k+1)\pi-(n+2)]|>\sin1\,.$

If $\;\frac\pi2+k\pi<n<1-\frac\pi2+(k+1)\pi\,,\;$ then $\,(k+1)\pi-\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)<n+1<(k+1)\pi+\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)\,,\;$ so $\,-\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)<(k+1)\pi-(n+1)<\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)\,,\;$ therefore $\,\cos[(k+1)\pi-(n+1)]>\cos\left(\frac\pi2-1\right)=\sin1\,,\;$ hence $\,|\cos(n+1)|=|\cos[(k+1)\pi-(n+1)]|>\sin1\,.$

Consequently, in any case, for any $\,n\in\Bbb Z\,,\,$ it results that $\,|\cos n|>\sin1\,$ or $\,|\cos(n+1)|>\sin1\,$ or $\,|\cos(n+2)|>\sin1\,.$

Comment: Why have you downvoted my answer?