# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos (nx)}{n^x}$ converges for $x>1$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> How can I go about showing that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos(nx)}{n^x}$converges for $x>1$ ?

Comment: What is the upper bound for $| \cos x |$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that $\frac{|\cos(nx)|}{n^x}\leq \frac{1}{n^x}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^x}<+\infty$ for $x>1$.
So by Comparison Test, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\cos (nx)}{n^x}$ is absolutely convergent and therefore it is also convergent.

P.S. Note that the series is conditionally convergent for $x=1$: [conditional convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(n)}{n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829299/conditional-convergence-of-sum-n-2-infty-frac-cosnn)

Comment: ahh ok I see, so it converges automatically since 1/n^x converges for x>1 ?

Comment: @dfge34 use comparison test and the fact that absolute convergence implies convergence.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** 
Use [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) .

Show  that for every positive $N$ there such $M$ number that  $\left| \sum _{ n=1 }^{ N } \cos  (nx) \right| \le M$ is bounded and $\frac { 1 }{ n^{ x } } $ monotone decreasing

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\cos(nx)$ is not bounded, it doesn't converge.  There exists a number $B$, such that for any $N$, $\left|\sum_{n=1}^{N}\cos(nx)\right|\le B$.

Comment: You're saing that it's not bounded in the first sentence, and then saying it's bounded in the second.